# Getting array out of bounds

Tags: java, string, repeat, indexoutofrangeexception

I am doing the hacker rank warmups and I have the logic down for repeating strings but am getting an string index out of range and not sure how to fix it. Could someone help with this?

```
public static long countAs(String s, long n) {

    long count;
    long length = s.length();
    long q = n / length;
    long r = n % length;

    long partial = 0;

    partial = r;

    count = q * getLetterCount(s, q) + getLetterCount(s, partial);


    return count;
}

public static long getLetterCount(String s, long length) {

    long count = 0;


    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {

        if (s.charAt(i) == 'a') {

            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: What is `n`? In the last iteration you essentially  do `s.charAt(n / length - 1)`. If `n > length^2` then you get the error. Also, this doesn't look like repeating a string at all. It rather looks like you are counting something.

Comment: Please show the call of `countAs()`

Comment: Sorry for confusion guys. N would be the string that I am counting the a's from. The idea is if I "aba" it will say that the string is q = |aba| r = abaabaa that way you dont have to brute your way though it. For the calling of getLetterCount(String s, Long l)

String s = "aba", Long l = 10  would be example parameters

Answer (score 2):

There is only one place in your code where that can happen:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (s.charAt(i) == 'a') { // <- HERE
        count++;
    }
}
```

When you are calling `s.chartAt(i)` most likely `i` is bigger than the size of the string `s`. Please check the value of `long length` you are passing to `getLetterCount()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
```

For this line, i is int and length is long, they have different value range!
when i = int_max +1 the runtime error will appear